# Examples of Python Objects That Have An __index__() method?

Tags: python, indexing, int, hex

What are some examples of Python objects that have an `__index__()` method other than an `int`?

For example, the [Hex](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#hex) documentation state:

> If `x` is not a Python int object, it has to define an `__index__()`
>   method that returns an integer.

This is for self-learning.

Comment: Anything that can be interpreted as an integer; e.g. **not** a floating point number (which can be *converted* to an integer but with loss of information). `bool` has that method because it is a subclass of `int`.  The idea being that such objects can be used as indices into a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly, these are types from mathematical libraries like [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) or [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html). These libraries have their own integer types (for good reason), but thanks to `__index__`, their special integers can be used as list indices or passed to `hex` like normal integers.

```
In [9]: import sympy

In [10]: x = sympy.Integer(1)

In [11]: x  # It looks like a regular 1, but it's not.
Out[11]: 1

In [12]: x/2  # This object has special behavior that makes sense for SymPy...
Out[12]: 1/2

In [13]: [1, 2, 3][x]  # but you can still use it for things like indexing.
Out[13]: 2
```